# How can I generalize a custom type call function to an abstract type?

Tags: types, julia, abstract

I have the following mock setup, with an abstract type, concrete types as subtypes, and a function `f` which takes two arguments, the first being a `Letter`.

```
abstract type Letter end

struct A <: Letter end
struct B <: Letter end

f(::A, x) = ('a', x)
f(::B, x) = ('b', x)

a = A()
b = B()
```

I would like to define a custom call function for `Letter` subtypes which simply calls `f`.

```
(t::A)(x) = f(t, x)
(t::B)(x) = f(t, x)
```

While this works, it seems quite redundant, especially considering that there could be many more subtypes of `Letter`. My attempts are as follows, but neither seem to work.

```
julia> (t::Letter)(x) = f(t, x)
ERROR: cannot add methods to an abstract type

julia> (t::T)(x) where T <: Letter = f(t, x)
ERROR: function type in method definition is not a type
```

How can I generalize a call function to match any (concrete) subtype of `Letter`?

Comment: Tricky, the only thing I got now is: `foreach(T->(t::T)(x) = f(t,x), subtypes(Letter))`

Comment: Your example is now working in Julia 1.0, just FYI.

Comment: @nix Are you sure? I see the same error messages on 1.0.

Comment: @HarrisonGrodin I am sorry I misunderstood your request. It is still not working now (v1.0.2).

Comment: It seems to be relevant to issue [#14919](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/14919), which is still open.

Comment: @nix Correct, it doesn't work on v1.0.2 - both of my given attempts still produce the same errors. As far as I'm aware, no changes have been made within Julia to officially support this behavior yet. This will be solved by #14919, though.

Answer (score 1):

Building on Dan's answer, metaprogramming seems to be the way to go

```
for T in Symbol.(subtypes(Letter))
    @eval (t::$T)(x) = f(t, x)
end
```

generates functions per type.

Or:

```
for T in Symbol.(subtypes(Letter))
    c = Char(lowercase(first(String(T))))
    @eval f(::$T, x) = ($c, x)
    @eval (t::$T)(x) = f(t, x)
end
```

However, this use of structs/subtypes as enums is [discouraged](https://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/style-guide/#Avoid-confusion-about-whether-something-is-an-instance-or-a-type-1)