# Parametric functors in Julia

Tags: julia, functor

Starting 0.6 it is possible to create parametric methods in Julia using `where` syntax. According to the [release notes of 0.6](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/master/NEWS.md) version, `where` syntax

> can be used anywhere a type is accepted

Now consider the following contrived example:

```
function (rng::R)() where {R <: Range}
    return first(rng)
end
```

which, when I attempt to compile it, gives the following error:

```
ERROR: function type in method definition is not a type
```

So my question is what is the proper way to create parametric functors in Julia 0.6+?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44597531/how-can-i-generalize-a-custom-type-call-function-to-an-abstract-type

Comment: this is [#14919](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/14919)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ohkay, I get what you are trying to do basically. To understand `functors` here is a short example code.

```
julia> struct Student
           name::String
       end

julia> function (::Student)()
           println("Callable of Student Type!")
       end

julia> object = Student("JuliaLang")
Student("JuliaLang")

julia> object()
Callable of Student Type!
```

but when I try to create the parametric functors, it throws out the error similar to yours!

```
julia> function (::T)() where {T <: Student}
           println("Callable of Student Type!")
       end
ERROR: function type in method definition is not a type
```

This problem is actually still `OPEN` as a issue as @gnimuc rightly pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

You mix up two things

- [parametric methods](https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/manual/methods/#Parametric-Methods-1) e.q. `julia> same_type(x::T, y::T) where {T} = true`
- [function-like objects](https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/manual/methods/#Function-like-objects-1) e.g. `julia> function (p::Polynomial)(x) ... end`

To my knowledge there is no "parametric function-like objects"

However, the following code should be the same of what you intend.

```
Julia> function (rng::Range)()
         return first(rng)
       end

       cannot add methods to an abstract type
```

The current docu does not mention any limitation of function-like objects to concrete type, but unfortunately Julia doesn't accept it anyway.

Comment: I am not mixing up anything, the question is precisely as formulated.

Comment: you mix parametric methods with function-like objects. there is no docu for that.

Comment: read the 0.6 release notes on `where` syntax. It says "...can be used anywhere a type is accepted"

Comment: Obviously the release notes are unprecise or wrong `isa(1, T) where {T <: Number}` or `supertype(T) where {T <: Int}` fails, too

Comment: which is why I am clarifying it. That's the whole point of the question. But there is no mixing up of anything, the question still holds as formulated!

Comment: You should read the whole context of your fragment of text: `New syntax Array{T} where T<:Integer, indicating a union of types over all specified values of T (represented by a UnionAll type). This provides behavior similar to parametric methods or typealias, but can be used anywhere a type is accepted. This syntax can also be used in method definitions` I read this as limitating the statement in the context of **Array{T}**

Comment: `This provides behavior similar to parametric methods or typealias, but can be used anywhere a type is accepted`. How else can you understand this??? Being limited to only `Array{T}` is clearly *not* `anywhere a type is accepted`!